# React Native Firebase: I'm trying to upload profile image via cloud storage but the function in 'then()' is not responding

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-storage, react-native-firebase

I'm trying to upload profile picture and for this I'm using firebase cloud storage and firebase real-time database, i've to call another function in then() but it's not working for some reason. Please correct my mistake..

```
uploadImage = async uri => {
  const response = await fetch(uri);
  const blob = await response.blob();
  var FilePath = imageId + '.' + this.state.currentFileType;
 
  storage()
    .ref('user/' + userid + './img')
    .child(FilePath)
    .put(blob)
    .then(snap => {
    snap.ref.getDownloadURL().then(downloadURL => {
    console.log(downloadURL);
    this.processUpload(downloadURL);
    });
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
  });
};
```

With catch callback, I'm getting this

> [TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating
> 'snap.ref.getDownloadURL')]

Comment: Your code is not checking for errors on the call to `put`.  You should chain a `catch` callback after `then` to see if something went wrong.

Comment: With catch callback i'm getting this "[TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'snap.ref.getDownloadURL')]"

Comment: OK, I suggest editing the question to include this new information.

Comment: What do you think is `undefined` here?  What exactly are you expecting this code to do?

Comment: I'm unable to figure it out what's undefined here honestly,  this code should generate downloadURL so that it can used as an argument of processUpload function..

Comment: Have you tried logging everything?  Stepping through in a debugger to see if everything contains the values you expect?